# continuous linear extension from Fréchet space $C^\infty(\Omega) $ to $C(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$   be an open subset, can we always extend a continuous linear functional on Fréchet space $C^\infty(\Omega)$ to a continuous linear functional on Fréchet space $C(\Omega)$?

---

I know if the extension exists, it must be the unique one, hence the map $(C(\Omega))' \to (C^\infty(\Omega))'$ is an injection. If the above result holds, it will an linear isomorphism, it seems not need to hold?

Comment: Hahn-Banach Theorem holds in general for topological vector spaces, so also for Fréchet-spaces.

Comment: @Bargabbiati then can continuous linear functional on Frechet space $C^\infty(\Omega)$ always has continuous extension to $C(\Omega)$?

Comment: If so we can identify $(C(\Omega))' = (C^\infty(\Omega)) '$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Frèchet topology for $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is stronger than the norm topology in $C(\Omega)$. So, even though you have an inclusion as vector spaces, you don't have one as Frèchet spaces.

For a concrete example, consider the continuous linear functional $f\longmapsto f'(1)$ on $C^\infty[0,1]$. On $\mathbb R[x]\subset C[0,1]$ this map is discontinuous.

Comment: do you mean some function in $C[0,1]$  is not differentiable?I can't figure out why $f'(1)$ is discontinuous on $C[0,1]$?

Comment: I have a indirect way to prove it,since  $f\mapsto f'(1)$ is distribution,it has compact supp,so it lies in $C^\infty(\Omega) ' $ but it does not correspond to Radon measure,all element in $C(\Omega)'$ is Radon measure so contradiction.

Comment: It doesn't extend, that's the point. Consider the sequence $\{p_n\}$ given by $p_n(t)=t^n$. Then $\|p_n\|=1$ for all $n$, but $p_n'(1)=n$.

Comment: norm topology on $C([0,1])$ coinside with Frechet topology on it correct?and $f\longmapsto f'(1)$ is distribution with compact support hence continuous on Frechet space $C^\infty[0,1]$ correct?

Comment: thanks I got the point,do you mean $f\longmapsto f'(1)$ is continuous functional under $(C^\infty([0,1]),Frechet)$  but if we extend it to $(C^1([0,1],norm)) = (C^1[0,1],Frechet)$ it can not be continuous since it's not a bounded linear map?

Comment: Frechet space $C^\infty$ has much large number of semi norm compared with semi norm for $C$, if extened the topology becomes much weaker,no longer makes it continuous linear functional

Comment: Yes. $ \ \ \ \ $